# Python PyAudio Updating audio devices info in program when mic disconnected

Tags: python, windows, audio, pyaudio, microphone

Win10/ I have a loop where I listen to the background with a microphone. I have a function, which shows me my current system audio devices (I setup the function to show microphones only).

Here it is:

```
def get_mics_list():
    mics = []
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
        if p.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name'] == 'Microsoft Sound Mapper - Input':
            pass
        elif p.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name'] == 'Microsoft Sound Mapper - Output':
            break
        else:
            mics.append(p.get_device_info_by_index(i))
    return mics
```

I chose the constant microphone device index for looping. Index = 1. The default microphone in the system. When I disconnect the microphone while looping, I catch the exception and continue looping with second (integrated in laptop) microphone, but I cannot update information about the current available system devices with that function. It still shows me two microphones, as it was before disconnection.

How can I update my system audio devices information in the program after changing the microphone?

Answer (score 1):

I found this question and was able to come up with a solution. Apparently, PyAudio does not allow you to update the list of devices **without reinitializing  it**. I don't know if anyone else needs this, but here's my solution:

I managed to update the list of devices only by calling the PyAudio again. So, make a def like this:

```py
def init_py_audio():
    # Opened for the first time
    if py_audio is None:
        py_audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    
    # Refresh
    else:
        py_audio.terminate()
        py_audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
```

And further, before getting a list of devices, call it like this:

```py
import pyaudio

py_audio = None


def get_mics_list():
    # Better use it inside a class and don't use global
    global py_audio

    # Opened for the first time
    if py_audio is None:
        py_audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    # Refresh
    else:
        py_audio.terminate()
        py_audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    mics = []
    info = py_audio.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)

    # List all devices
    for i in range(0, info.get('deviceCount')):
        # Check number of input channels
        # (If there is at least 1 input channel, then it is suitable as a microphone)
        if py_audio.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels') > 0:
            mics.append(py_audio.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name'))

    return mics

# Will update the device list every time it is called
print(get_mics_list())
```